# Expandable table when row is clicked, except for last cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a dynamically generated table that takes attendance for students. The rows will expand with additional information about the student, if any part of the row is clicked. My problem is that if the attendance button (red x) is clicked, then the row expands, but the attendance is marked just fine.

[image: Attendance Table]

I found a way to disable the last column (by giving all cells on the last column the same name and using some jquery to make it unclickable), but when doing that the buttons got disabled too.

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    //This is the line I used to disable the last column, but is affecting the buttons
    $('td[name="attend"]').click(function () {
        return false;
    });

    //the rest of the code is used for expanding each row
    $("td[colspan=7]").find("p").hide();
    $("table").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $(event.target);
        if ($target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1) {
            $target.slideUp();
        } else {
            $target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
        }
    });
});
```

I have named all the cells in the last column "attend". Any help is much appreciated!

Upon Request, here is the code for each button. Each button is it's own form that is inside the last cell of every row.
**php**

```
 echo "<td style=\"min-width:75px;\" name=\"attend\">";
    echo "<form method=\"POST\" onSubmit=\"return new_user(this);\" >";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . $row2['status'] . "\" name=\"astatus\" />";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . $row2['cancel_key'] . "\" name=\"mark_attend\" />";
    echo "<input type=\"image\" src=\"$image\" name=\"pic\" />";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</td>";
```

Comment: simple... if target is attendance button, don't expand...

Comment: Well the logic is simple, but I'm looking for an answer with more syntax. I'm not an expert at javascript/jquery

Comment: Post your code that handles marking attendance.

Comment: The syntax is relatively simple too. `if ($(event.target).is(selectorthatmatchesbutton)) { /*don't expand*/}`

Comment: Could also `stopPropagation` in the click handler for the button.

Comment: @JasonP I added in the code that handles the button

Answer (score 0):

Examine the target tag name like so:

```
 alert($target.prop('tagName'));
```

It will be "TD" (or SPAN, or whatever is in the cell), or your button.